# MySQL backup doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to backup a MySQL database called `Reservebox`to a .gzip file. I got this script from a tutorial, and I changed the values according to my values. The problem is when I click submit nothing happens. I do not know where did I go.

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="backup.php">
    <input type="submit" name="Backup" id="Backup" value="Backup" />
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<?php
    include ("functions_cp/f_connection.php");
    Sqlconnection();

    $dbname = "Reservebox";
    $dbhost = "localhost";
    $dbuser = "root";
    $dbpass = "123";

    function backup() {
        $backupFile = $dbname . date("Y-m-d-H-i-s") . '.gz';
        $command = "mysqldump --opt -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass $dbname | gzip > $backupFile";
        system($command);
    }
    if(isset($_POST['backup'])) {
        backup();
    }
```

Comment: Why don't you BACKUP using PHPMyAdmin ? Its super-easy !

Comment: check logs. Perhaps your PHP config doesn't allow using system

Comment: i do know who gives me -1 but OK ! , @sh4nx0r i need to learn how ! I KNOW THAT I CAN USE PHPMYADMIN :)

Comment: Are there any shell metacharacters `&^$;|><` in your password or database name? Does your webserver have privileges to write directly in its current working directory? (Almost certainly not. If it does, I'd say that is probably a misconfiguration that is asking for a security flaw.)

Comment: @BaderHAlRayyes, I never downvote , so grab some H20.

Comment: @sh4nx0r thanks for your help , i did not say it was you :)

Comment: @sarnold no i do not have these characters on my password, how can check the webserver privileges

Comment: Hey, if you add `echo` in front of the `system()`, will it give you the error message just like that?

Comment: @sarnlod i changed the file type to sql and it worked , however the file i got is empty , any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(isset($_POST['backup'])) {`
I think the backup on this line needs a capital B!

If that doesn't sort it, try adding `error_reporting(E_ALL);` on a new line after `<?php`.

Comment: after i added the error_reporting , it gives me this "Notice: Undefined variable: dbname , and all other vars with same message , i put them all inside the function `backup` , the error gone but also nothing happens agains , it appears the when i click the button something loads for a bit but no file to download.

Comment: The notices are okay.  The code you have shown us doesn't show that a file is meant to be returned.  It's going to write a .gz file to the file system. You should go look for it :)

Comment: i changed the type to .sql and it worked , however the file i generate is empty, any suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the space between the `-p` and `$dbpass`.

Also, remove `--opt`. That is not strictly necessary.